# Django Advanced Filtering

Tags: django, view, filter, django-queryset

Can I filter a queryset based on a model field's choices?

model:

```
COLORS = (
    ('BLACK', 'black'),
    ('RED', 'red'),
    ('BLUE', 'blue'),
    //etc..
)

class Thing(Models.model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=COLORS)
```

view:

```
def filter_by_color(request):
    q = Thing.objects.filter(???)
```

Is there a way to filter `Thing` based on different color choices? Also, is there a way to write this dynamically, so that all color choices can respond to a single view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

view

```
def filter_by_color(request, color):
     q = Thing.objects.filter(color=color)
```

So when you access  `http://yoursite/thisview/black` you will get `Thing`s with black color and when you access `http://yoursite/thisview/red` you will get `Thing`s with red color .

Comment: This is very helpful. But if you wanted to contain all color choices within a single url `http://yoursite/thisview/` and filter the color choices within that view, would you need to use ajax to modify your queryset each time a user selects a different color? It seems like there would be a better way...

Comment: @NickB I'm sorry I don't get what you want to say and achieve.

Comment: I just mean:  is there a way to filter a queryset differently without having to visit a different url? So the user does not have to refresh the page? Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 3):

You should look into [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects. That can help you construct complex OR queries depending on what colors the user is choosing to filter on.

**UPDATE** Adding an example.

Assuming that you want to filter on more than one color:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def filter_by_color(request):

    q = Thing.objects.filter(Q(color="BLACK") | Q(color="RED))
```

**UPDATE 2** If the user selects the colors with checkboxes or similar you can use this approach:

```
def filter_by_color(request):
    selected_colors = request.GET.getlist('colors')

    q = Thing.objects.filter(color__in=selected_colors)
```

Comment: Hi Mikael. Can you give me an example of how you would use a Q object in this case? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Hi Nick, I have added an example. How are you planning to pass the selected color's from the client to the view?